# After declaring an array of translations including Hebrew characters, str_replace() does not replace substrings as expected

Tags: php, arrays, replace, right-to-left, hebrew

I have an array with Hebrew words that I need to find in a string and replace. The translation array is defined as key-value pairs.

**In English, this works.**

```
   function replace_twophrase_words($string) {

    $string = strtolower($string);

    $replacements = array (
        'movers'                =>  'Moving Services',
        'home-moving'           =>  'Home Moving',
        'commercial-moving'     =>  'office-moving',
    );


    $string = str_replace($replacements, array_keys($replacements), $string);
}
```

**Hebrew array (asked in comments):**

```
$replacements = array (
    'עיצוב-פנים'            =>  'עיצוב פנים',
    'עיצוב-פנים'            =>  'מעצבת פנים',
    'עיצוב-פנים'            =>  'עיצוב משרדים',
);
```

But... it seems that this doesn't work in Hebrew at all.
Can anyone explain what's gone wrong?

Comment: This is PHP code? (you should tag the language)

Comment: You should post a separate code block showing the code with the Hebrew words. Might help people help you.

Comment: done & done.. thanks for the comments. tagged the lang & added Heb Array for example.

Comment: It seemed to work for me. Of course all the `$replacement` values are the same so I changed them to be unique, but when I used Hebrew keys it pulled correct value.

Comment: no way ;) to my regret, currently this doesnt work. did you try to echo the result? here is some text you can test on "אני מעצב פנים מנוסה אשר מספק שירותי עיצוב פנים מקצועיים במחירים נדירים" ... this verb "עיצוב פנים" should turn to this "עיצוב-פנים" in the output.

Comment: i would ofcourse love to be wrong - but can you share an example of your code? i tested and tested many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [mb_ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php):

```
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8' );
header( 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' );
echo mb_ereg_replace( 'עיצוב-פנים', 'עיצוב פנים', 'Hebrew string is here: עיצוב-פנים ; and back to Latin.' );
```

This is because Hebrew letters are composed of multiple bytes and str_reaplce and preg_replace (by default) do not understand these.

Comment: The function only takes strings, so you will need to loop your list of replacements through with: foreach.

Comment: going to give it a try... brb

Comment: having internet issuses here (anwering fron phone ;) ) as soon as i can check it.

Comment: This answer's snippet makes no replacements because the `find` value is never found in the haystack string.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that has tripped you up is not the behavior of native PHP functions, but in the way that you've defined your lookup array containing Right-To-Left characters.

Your array is declared as:

```
$replacements = array (
    'עיצוב-פנים'  =>  'עיצוב פנים',
    'עיצוב-פנים'  =>  'מעצבת פנים',
    'עיצוב-פנים'  =>  'עיצוב משרדים',
);
```

Notice that with the RTL strings, the direction of the `=>` is also affected. If you print it out with `var_export()`, you get:

```
array (
  'עיצוב-פנים' => 'עיצוב משרדים',
)
```

You see the three identical values on the right side of each line are *actually* the keys and PHP does not let you have duplicate keys on a single level of an array.  So your data not only collapses, it doesn't work as intended for the replacement task.

---

To correct your data, reverse the position of your intended keys and values. `[value <= key, ...]`

```
$replacements = array(
    'עיצוב פנים' => 'עיצוב-פנים',
    'מעצבת פנים' => 'עיצוב-פנים',
    'עיצוב משרדים' => 'עיצוב-פנים',
);
```

Then `echo strtr($input, $replacements);` will work exactly as desired.

`str_replace()` will also work but you'll need to isolate the keys as an array of values and pass the find and replacement parameters separately.  Because all of your replacements are the same, if you are going to use `str_replace()`, you could just write the single string value as the 2nd parameter.

Here is a demo of everything discussed above. https://3v4l.org/pms5Z